# How can I calculate the correlation coefficients on the third dimension of an array?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, correlation

Say, I have an array three dimensions, with items as rows, items as columns, participants as third dimension and values in co-occurence counts.
Notice further that each of the array "slices" (= item x item matrices) is symmetrical (because they're co-occurence counts!).

Like so:

```
a <- structure(c(17L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 17L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 17L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 16L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 18L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 18L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L, 3L), .Dimnames = structure(list(items = c("but-how", "encyclopedia", "alien", "comma"), items = c("but-how", "encyclopedia", "alien", "comma"), people = c("Julius", "Tashina", "Azra")), .Names = c("items", "items", "people")))
```

I now want the correlation coefficients matrix of participants x participants, that is, the respective coefficients for `Julius`, `Tashina` and `Azra`.
To do that, I'd just want to correlate their respective cells in the two matrices, so for `Azra` and `Tashina`, I'd correlate their respective upper (or lower) triangles.

It's not obvious to me how to do this, since `cor()` and friends don't accept arrays.

I can hack-do this via some `apply()` and `upper.tri()` action, like in the below, but I am guessing **there has to be a more efficient, matrix-magical way** to do this, right?

---

Here's the hacky way I'm doing this now. Don't laugh.

```
loosedat <- apply(X = a, MARGIN = c(3), FUN = function(x) {
    x <- x[upper.tri(x = x, diag = FALSE)]  # must kill diagonal, will otherwise inflate results
})  
cor(loosedat)
```

Gets me what I want, but I feel dirty doing it.

```
           Julius   Tashina     Azra
Julius  1.0000000 0.4472136 0.522233
Tashina 0.4472136 1.0000000 0.700649
Azra    0.5222330 0.7006490 1.000000
```

Comment: hold on a sec, you're too quick for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
n <- dim(a)[3L]    ## number of people
m <- dim(a)[1L]    ## square table dimension
id <- dimnames(a)[[3L]]    ## name of people
uptri <- upper.tri(diag(m))    ## upper triangular index
loosedat <- matrix(as.numeric(a)[uptri], ncol = n, dimnames = list(NULL, id))
#     Julius Tashina Azra
#[1,]      1       0    1
#[2,]      0       0    2
#[3,]      0       0    1
#[4,]      1       1    3
#[5,]      1       0    2
#[6,]      0       0    0

cor(loosedat)
#           Julius   Tashina     Azra
#Julius  1.0000000 0.4472136 0.522233
#Tashina 0.4472136 1.0000000 0.700649
#Azra    0.5222330 0.7006490 1.000000
```

You can squeeze above code into a single line. But for readable demonstration I take the step-by-step approach.

Comment: thanks; this sure seems a lot faster.
I'm still wondering whether there might be *matrix* algebra-way to do this, as (perhaps?) described [here](http://stats.seandolinar.com/making-a-covariance-matrix-in-r/).
That seems to go via the difference matrix, then covariance matrix (which would do, for now).

Would you know whether that might *still* be faster?

Thanks so much for the code, I'll add the benchmarks here myself.